# Grouping layers by attribute value and finding nearest neighbour using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, grouping

I am new to QGIS.

I have two layers (`layer_a` and `layer_b`) consisting of two sets of points.

If I want to find the nearest point in `layer_b` for each point in `layer_a`, I can just use the [Distance matrix calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#distance-matrix) that comes with the graphical interface in QGIS.

My issue is slightly more complicated. I want to group both layers by an attribute value, before I calculate the distance between points.

Translation: if `layer_a` has a bunch of points to libraries around the world and `layer_b` has a bunch of points to big cities around the world, and both layers have an attribute where the value tells me which country each point is in, then I want to find the shortest distance between a library point in a specific country and a big city point in the same country.

I could accomplish this by splitting the layers by country and then repeating the analysis on each layer (i.e. distance between library points in Germany and big city points in Germany), using the graphical interface in QGIS, but this is tedious. Also, in reality I will have thousands of groups.

How do I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for a PyQGIS solution then ask that in a separate question.